# What would a good low variance quantile estimator be?

Tags: quantiles

I'm new to quantile estimation. I have a bunch of iid random variables, say $X_1, \dots, X_m \sim p^\star$. Suppose I don't know their law.

Supposing my cdf is $F$, I want to estimate quantiles $q_1 = F^{-1}(1/k), q_2=F^{-1}(2/k), \dots, q_{k-1} = F^{-1}(1-1/k)$, for a $k$ given a low variance estimator, ideally something like

$$\sum_{i,j}\text{Covar}(\hat q_i, \hat q_j) = o(1/m)$$

Does such an estimator exist?

What if I suppose that there is a law $p$ such that $TV(p, p^\star) \leq \epsilon$, and that I have full information on $p$ ? For example, if $p$ is $U(0,1)$ or $\mathcal N(0,1)$?

Comment: It's hard to imagine how one could do better than the sample quantiles, so as a start have you examined the asymptotic behavior of their covariances?  That's an illuminating exercise; in particular, it shows that for such results to hold, you need to make assumptions about the density of $F$ in neighborhoods of its quantiles: namely, that it is nonzero.

Comment: Right, under good assumptions, i.e. the density $f$ is non zero everywhere, the best reference I've found is [this tutorial](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Tutorial-on-Quantile-Estimation-via-Monte-Dong-Nakayama/d1941f5b3dbc0352432ef1631b6137b7e0de9624) for trying to use an auxiliary variable (the control variates section). It seems counter intuitive to me that knowledge of your distribution within a small TV ball doesn't help much for quantile estimation -- i.e. you can't do better than outputting either the quantiles of the known distribution or the sample quantiles.

Comment: If you have so good knowledge of your distribution, maybe you can use a parametric model? then you will get more efficient quantile estimators